# Tags in the main window of the Unanswered page don't filter on only the unanswered questions

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

Scenario - I'm in SO and I click on the big "Unanswered" button at the top of the page - this lists a bunch of unanswered questions - all good. Each of these questions have a number of tag buttons under them - the tags that are relevant for the question. However, if I click on these tags (so I can filter the unanswered questions to only this tag) it redirects to `/questions/tagged/<tagname>` instead of `/unanswered/tagged/<tagname>`. By contrast, clicking one of the tag buttons on the right under the "Unanswered Tags" section works correctly.

The logic behind this doesn't seem right - if I'm on the page of Unanswered questions, I would expect the tag buttons under each question would show me only the *unanswered* questions for that tag, not *all* questions for that tag. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: +1 Makes sense, would be nice -- but I suspect it won't be implemented, as tag buttons always link to the same place.

Comment: This isn't a bug, all tag links go to the same place in *all* cases, it's very consistent behavior across the site.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary.

Within the `/questions/tagged/<tagname>` page is a tab for 'unanswered':

[image]

This tab (located at `/questions/tagged/<tagname>?sort=unanswered`) is slightly different than the `/unanswered` page, but it's probably close enough. `/unanswered` here means no upvoted answers and has tabs for sorting by 'my tags' (not really useful here), 'newest', 'votes', and 'no answers'.  The `/questions?sort=unanswered` tab sorts questions without accepted or upvoted answers by reverse answer count. I don't spend a lot of time on these tabs, but I'm not sure that the minor differences here are worth changing the behavior of all the tags.

If you click this tab, the next time you click a tag in or beneath a question (at least in the current session, I didn't test it through a logout and login cycle), it will sort on this 'unanswered' tab.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but for me the Unanswered button at the top is much better than the Unanswered tab under the question. Specifically for me, I like to use the Unanswered button to show the Newest questions that need answering - you can't do this using the Unanswered tab because it sorts them by votes. I find the Button and the Tab serve very different purposes.